# None of my snaps are starting Permission denied

Tags: snap

Discord and qemu stopped working with this latest update.
There seems to be a permissions problem with the snap user.

As a for instance

```
/snap/discord/128/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 50: /home/captain/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied


/snap/discord/128/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch : line 261:  permission denied

Failed to generate minidump.Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On 21.04 gnome.

Comment: Segmentation fault  This is a memory fault and sometimes a hard disk error. Run the mem test from the list at startup. Also what is 21.04 gnome?

Comment: @David 21.04 is the Ubuntu version I'm using. Gnome is the desktop environment. Not sure what other interpretation could have been rendered on askubuntu.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

None of the usual remedies helped. I ended up doing a new install. Things are working better than before.

This was from an original 18.04 upgraded to 21.04.